# Prove or disprove: A connected undirected Graph G has no Bridge/cut-edge if G is 2k-regular

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, solution-verification, graph-connectivity

//Bridge/Cut-edge if after deleting the edge the Graph is not connected anymore.

I think its not true because you could build a Graph G with **2k** disconnected-components where in each component exists one node with degree **2k-1**. And then you connect all these nodes with degree **2k-1** with a single node in the middle which has degree **2k** --> G becomes a connected Graph. And if you delete any of the edges which connect the node in the middle with one of the components you get a disconnected Graph. Hence there exists a bridge.

Can somebody verify my solution or tell me if i made a mistake? And i still need to formalize my solution obviously.

Comment: In your proposed construction, the components have exactly one vertex of odd degree, but that's not possible, since the sum of the degrees must be even.

Comment: The vertex with odd degree should get a even degree when theyre connected to my "middle" vertex. But i failed to draw this and might need to think of sth else.

Comment: But before the connection, the component has exactly one vertex of odd degree, which is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying for a counterexample (which would be futile), try instead for a proof.

**Hints:**

Suppose edge $ab$ is a bridge of $G$, and let $H=G-ab$.

- By definition of bridge, $H$ is not connected.$\\[4pt]$

  Argue that vertices $a,b$ cannot be in the same component of $H$.$\\[4pt]$

  If $A$ is the component of $H$ which contains $a$, argue that all vertices of $A$ other than $a$ have the same degree in $A$ as they had in $G$.$\\[4pt]$

  Now consider the degree of $a$ in $A$.$\\[4pt]$

  So then in $A$, the sum of the degrees has what parity?

Comment: a in A has an uneven degree since 2k-1=always uneven. Hence in A the sum of degrees has an uneven parity. The same goes for the other component i suppose and in total there is an even degree again.
--> No matter how many edges are deleted i will always have a connected graph? Because for every deleted edge there is another one because of **2**k ?

Comment: i got it: in every Graph G the number of vertices with uneven degree is even which is a contradiction